# Probability that the number $(a^3 + b^3)$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: probability

> Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are chosen from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots 3n\}$. Find the probability that $(a^3 + b^3)$ is divisible by $3$.

I am  not able to check whether the cube of a number is divisible by $3$.

Comment: `I am not able to check whether cube of a number is divisible by 3` Hint $a^3 \equiv a \pmod 3\,$.

Comment: Can a and b be equal?

Comment: @fleablood I would assume so, unless explictly stated otherwise (if they can't be equal, it becomes a more difficult "without replacement" scenario).

Comment: If a =1 0 mod 3 then b needs to to be 0 mod 3.  Prob is (1/3)((n-1)/(3n-1)). If a = 1 mod 3 then b needs to be 2mod 3.  The proof is (1/3)(n/(3n-1)) reverse for a =2 mod 3.  So prob is (n-1+n+n)(3 (3n-1))=(3n-1)/3 (3n-1) = 1/3.  There may be an easier way.

Comment: Actually whether you can or can't the answer is the same.

Comment: Oh...  a^3 mod 3 = a mod 3 as 0^3=0 1^3= 1 and 2^3 = 8. (or -1^3=-1).

Comment: Did I do it wrong?   Prob both are zero mod three $\frac 13\frac {n-1}{3n-1}$.  Prob first is mod one and second is mod 2 $\frac 13\frac n{3n-1}$. Prob first is mod two and second is mod 1 $\frac 13\frac n{3n-1}$ Add them:$ \frac {(n-1)+n + n}{3(3n-1)}=\frac {3n-1}{3(3n-1)} = \frac 13$.  How did you get the prob is $\frac n{3n-1}$?

Comment: @fleablood I must apologise, I was wrong. You were right. I listed the numbers in recurring triples modulo $3$ as $(1,-1,0)$. But for some strange reason, it didn't hit me that the $0$ case was distinct from the other two. Yes, the probability is $\frac 13$ either way.

Comment: It was an easy mistake to make.  The answer 1/3 surprised me for the exact same reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2) = (a+b)((a+b)^2 - 3ab)$

Comment: That was that simple... thank u